# Can I obtain the colormap (custom) position for an RGB pixel?

Tags: python, numpy, colors, pixel, colormap

I did the tutorial on numpy [https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html], but I didn't find any tutorial to get the colormap position for an RGB pixel eg. (100, 150, 100, 1). Any ideas ??

I ended up iterating for every color exist in my colormap:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import time

magma = cm.get_cmap('magma',256)
bottom = cm.get_cmap('binary',256)
##print(magma(0.5))

newcolors=np.vstack((bottom(np.linspace(0,1,128)),magma(np.linspace(0,1,128))))
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors)

def colorfinder(colormap,pixel,delta):
    for i in range(len(colormap)):
        if(pixel[0]>newcolors[i][0]-delta and pixel[0]<newcolors[i][0]+delta):
            if(pixel[1]>newcolors[i][1]-delta and pixel[1]<newcolors[i][1]+delta):
                if(pixel[2]>newcolors[i][2]-delta and pixel[1]<newcolors[i][2]+delta):
                    print(i)

dot=np.zeros(4)
dot=[0/256,16/256,110/256,1]
colorfinder(newcolors,dot,0.037)
```

Comment: Have you tried using 'gray' instead of 'magma'? It should make a grayscale colormap.  [This link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) has more information for the same.

Comment: @Jitesh what is the different ? I could display the colormap...... but, for example, I have a color, let's say its perfect orange..... where is the position of this orange color in my custom colormap ?? is it in the middle or top,.... how ??

Comment: I could look up and match my orange to every color exist in my color map...... but I will do this procedure with thousands of images... any more effective method ?

Comment: If you write `print(magma(0.4))` at the end of your script, then it will show you the color (0.550287, 0.161158, 0.505719, 1.0), which might be difficult to get reverse. But if you use grayscale then the output of `print(gray(0.4))` will be (0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0), which is easy for your solution. (Intuition: If you convert the orange color to gray (o to 1), then that would be its position). Sorry if I didn't understand the main problem.

Comment: @Jitesh thanks for your rapid response, unfortunately, I'm working with 3-channel images, I ended up iterating for every color in color map, its not really that slow. lol